# How to unblock a blocked task in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

How do you change the Blocked status of a task from Yes to No?  We don't see No as an option in the dropdown after we set the Blocked state to Yes.

I have searched Google and SO to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oooh boy. How's this for an unintuitive answer.  You just delete the word Yes from the Blocked dropdown and it's no longer blocked.

Comment: Obvious, but wrong.  It gives the error "The field 'Blocked' contains the value 'No' that is not in the list of supported values."

Comment: This is the correct answer. Delete the word Yes and leave the field blank.